# Can I display a file size in a file type input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, html, visual-studio-2010

I am working with a file type input. I would like to display the file size after the file has been selected. I am thinking I should use some jquery to pull that, but I am not sure how. Can I do that?

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile"/>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. The user is only selecting the path to the file that is to be uploaded, they're not sending an actual file at that specific time, and it is possible that the file size would change between the time of selection and time that the file is *actually* uploaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should show it if the browser has the capability (firefox, chrome, opera(?) ):

```
jQuery( "#uploadFile").bind( "change", function(){
    if( this.files && this.files.length ) { //If this condition passes, you can get file size
    var file = this.files[0],
    fileSize = file.size || file.fileSize || 0;
    alert(fileSize+ " bytes" );
    }
});
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/yNQ9M/1/ (updated to work in firefox and opera)

You can also use ActionScript (Flash) hacks to do it in older browsers.

Microsoft is working on the [File API in ie10](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2011/04/first-preview-of-internet-explorer-10-arrives-with-new-features.ars)

Comment: This only works in Google Chrome. Firefox and Opera both display "undefined bytes" and the alert does not trigger at all in IE9.

Comment: Perhaps it did once and they removed support for it. I tested in Firefox 7.

Comment: it is working (otherwise alert wouldn't show up at all) I need to account for a difference in the property, fix coming up.

Comment: The alert is working fine, yes, but it displays "undefined bytes" since fileSize is not defined... Chrome was the only browser that showed a number.

Comment: THanks, I really appreciate it. So the cross browser functionality issue is not a worry?

Comment: the fact that `this.files && this.files.length` passed meant there is File API available, it was just the property name I had wrong. IE9 Doesn't show the alert at all because it has no support.